# Can I train a neural network with the singular values ​of an image?

Tags: php, neural-network, svd

I made a convolutional neural network in php with backpropagation and gradient descent. I then downloaded a training set containing dog images and trained the neural network so that all the errors were close to 10 ^ -6 for each image in the set. To save computing power I calculated the SVD of the grayscale image and trained the neural network on the diagonal (the sigma matrix), normalizing all values ​​to the largest eigenvalue. The result was not very good, because when I tried to refer a cat it was recognized as a dog. Do you think it is impossible to train a neural network in this way? Am I bound to pass all the pixels of the grayscale image of the training set one by one? In this case do you recommend to dimensionless with respect to the maximum value (255)? Thank you so much in advance for your contribution!

Comment: Are you using php for this?

Comment: Yes, I wrote my neural network from scratch by building all the necessary mathematical applications (scalar products, internal products etc.)
The network converges but it doesn't necessarily work. Unfortunately, I don't think there is a mechanism to determine if backpropagation happens correctly or not